# What is the appropriate HTTP status for login failed

Tags: angularjs, http, authentication

I have an API for logging in my AngularJS app. It just posts to a login URL and then gets a session object back if it went well. If it goes wrong however, what would be the right HTTP code to answer?

- 401: Unauthorized. Well not really. The user is authorized to try and login, it's just that the credentials were wrong.
- 400: Bad Request. Well not really. I understood the request, it's just that the credentials didn't match up.

If you think 401 would be best, that runs into another problem: I have an interceptor to catch 401s and show the login modal as a result. The idea is that a 401 will only happen when a session has expired (or something about the user changed), and the user should re-authenticate.

What would be the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

The API should return 400: Bad Request only when the data is truly in bad form.

I'd return 422: Unprocessable Entity

Here are two articles:

http://www.restpatterns.org/HTTP_Status_Codes/422_-_Unprocessable_Entity
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2434-http-status-codes-for-invalid-data-400-vs-422.htm